# Create Table with ng repeat with nested JSON Object

Tags: angularjs, json, object, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create a table form this json object which the headers of table are `service_name` and It's `action_name's` are in rows.

```
    $scope.aclTest = {
    "1": {
        service_name: 'acl', actions: {
            "1": { action_name: "test11", id: 1 },
            "2": { action_name: "test12", id: 2 },
            "3": { action_name: "test13", id: 3 },
            "4": { action_name: "test14", id: 4 },
            "5": { action_name: "test15", id: 5 }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        service_name: 'gps', actions: {
            "1": { action_name: "test21", id: 1 },
            "2": { action_name: "test22", id: 2 },
            "3": { action_name: "test23", id: 3 }
        }
    },
    "3": {
        service_name: 'sms', actions: {
            "1": { action_name: "test31", id: 1 },
            "2": { action_name: "test32", id: 2 },
            "3": { action_name: "test33", id: 3 },
            "4": { action_name: "test34", id: 4 }
        }
    }
};
```

I need somthing like this :

```
acl                     gps                      sms
-----                   -----                     ----- 
test11                 test21                    test31
test12                 test22                    test32
test13                 test23                    test33
test14                                           test34
test15
```

How can I do that with ng repeat?

Comment: It would much easier if you don't need a `table` element. Is a `table` element a must have? You could achieve the same view by using `div` much easier.

Comment: Any feedback m8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c0d02yeg/)**. It's much more easy to display this data in `div` than using `table` elements. If you want to use `table` elements you need to restructure your JSON Data.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in aclTest" style="float:left;margin-right:25px;">
     <h3 style="font-weight: bold;font-size: 18px;border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
      {{ item.service_name }}
     </h3> 
    <div ng-repeat="subItem in item.actions">
        {{ subItem.action_name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.aclTest = {
    "1": {
        service_name: 'acl', actions: {
            "1": { action_name: "test11", id: 1 },
            "2": { action_name: "test12", id: 2 },
            "3": { action_name: "test13", id: 3 },
            "4": { action_name: "test14", id: 4 },
            "5": { action_name: "test15", id: 5 }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        service_name: 'gps', actions: {
            "1": { action_name: "test21", id: 1 },
            "2": { action_name: "test22", id: 2 },
            "3": { action_name: "test23", id: 3 }
        }
    },
    "3": {
        service_name: 'sms', actions: {
            "1": { action_name: "test31", id: 1 },
            "2": { action_name: "test32", id: 2 },
            "3": { action_name: "test33", id: 3 },
            "4": { action_name: "test34", id: 4 }
        }
    }
};
});
```